# using statement and usage of resource in an event

Tags: c#, memory-management

I just wanted to clarify this. Is this safe in terms of disposing the client:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient(TimeoutInSeconds))
{
   client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(par.Base_url));
   client.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, e) =>
   {
       //code that checks e.Result
   }
}
```

And related question: suppose my client goes out of scope (has no references to it), without being properly disposed could the memory be cleaned from its data?

And also if client is disposed, then where `e.Result` resides?
Could anyone clarify this?

Comment: Even in the case that the `client` object may throw an exception this code will clean up any resources that this object may be using.  So yes it is valid.

Comment: how do you mean where e.Result resides, can you clarify?

Comment: using statement always cleans ups up and release resources no matter what

Comment: I think part of what the OP is asking:  Is it okay to Dispose of WebClient while the DownloadDataSync operation is still going on.  In the code, there is a race between the DownloadDataSync completing and the the client getting disposed.

Comment: @James Michael Hare What I mean is whether e.Result is actually valid if client is disposed. My guess is that e.Result is pointing to some data structure of WebClient, so if it is immediately disposed then it shouldn't be valid. But my tests show it is valid. Well, I certainly hope that e.Result is not copy of the whole client's data...

Comment: That's just an instance of WebClient that gets disposed. Even if you're using something from that namespace, you shouldn't care if the WebClient instance is gone to be able to handle the result. Meaning, it should work fine as is.

Comment: @paabobo Actually, there are exceptional circumstances that can result in it not happening, for example when using `Thread.Abort`.

Comment: You should subscribe to the event prior to calling the async method. Though very unlikely, it is theoretically possible for the async task to complete prior to your next statement and then you would lose the completion event.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.0, the `WebClient` class inherits the `Dispose` method from `System.ComponentModel.Component`. Since it doesn't override the `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` method, disposing of the class only runs the cleanup from the base class - namely, it removes the component from the `ISite`'s container, if any, and raises the `Disposed` event. Since you're not assigning a site and you're not subscribing to the `Disposed` event, there's actually no need to call `Dispose` at all.

While the code certainly looks like it should fail, at least in .NET 4.0, it won't.